# Double-bar notation for second-order tensors

Tags: math-mode, typography, accents

I want to use the double-bar notation for second-order tensors, which is common in continuum mechanics (e.g. for the strain and stress tensors).

I've searched the Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List but failed to find anything conclusive in there.

I've found [this discussion](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=2759), in which Stefan and Thorsten propose the alternatives below.

**Is there a preferred way of typesetting this accent?**

Subsidiary question: what is the difference between `\bar` and `\Bar`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\bar{\bar\tau} \quad
\Bar{\Bar\tau} \quad
\overline{\overline\tau}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\show\Bar` gives `\bar` so no difference (at least in `amsmath`)

Comment: `amsmath.sty` has `\def\Bar{\bar}`, so (as percusse said) there's no difference (in `amsmath`).

Comment: In a previous version of `amsmath`, in order to get double accents one had to use the uppercase variant; this is no longer necessary from `amsmath` version 2. The old commands have been retained for backwards compatibility.

Comment: There's also the Unicode combining character U+033F ◌̿ "COMBINING DOUBLE OVERLINE", which seems to introduce less vertical space between the two horizontal bars stacked: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overline#Unicode

Answer (score 23, accepted):

egreg's comment comforted me in the thought that both `\bar{\bar{...}}` and `\overline{\overline{...}}` can be used to typeset double accents without any nasty side effects.

However, the best way to replicate the double-bar notation for rank-2 tensors, as found [there](http://www.ics.uzh.ch/~teyssier/cm_lecture10.pdf), for instance, seems to be using `\overline{\overline{...}}`.

`\overline{\overline{...}}` should be preferred to `\bar{\bar{...}}` because the `\overline` produces a vinculum of the same width as its argument, whereas `\bar` only produces a vinculum of fixed width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*{\rttensor}[1]{\overline{\overline{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\rttensortwo}[1]{\bar{\bar{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
$\rttensor{\epsilon} \quad \rttensor{\sigma} \quad \rttensor{G}$\\[1em]
$\rttensortwo{\epsilon} \quad \rttensortwo{\sigma} \quad \rttensortwo{G}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Aesthetically, however, \bar\bar is more pleasing than \overline\overline.

Comment: @JohnRos Not to me, especially if the tensor name is long.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes second rank tensors are denoted with underbars, per

[image]

and that's

```
\underline{\underline{\mathbf{G}}}
```

The `\underbar` doesn't work as well in that case.

Comment: this solution is inferior, though, because the variable is no longer displayed italic