# Double-bar notation for second-order tensors4

Tags: underline, tensor, bar

I found it interesting to represent a tensor with the notation normally used by my professor. Looking for respect to the mathematical symbol I found this code from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107223/double-bar-notation-for-second-order-tensors), very interesting.

I would like to insert this command below,I modified the code but the result with '\underline' is not pleasant

```
\newcommand*{\rttensor}[1]{\underline{\underline{#1}}}
\overline{u'_{i}u'_{j}u'_{i,j}} = \rttensor{T}
```

but the result is not satisfactory. The command with `\bar` is aesthetically superior, but I can not find a way to put it underneath

```
\newcommand*{\rttensortwo}[1]{\bar{\bar{#1}}}

\overline{(\rho'u'_{i})} = \rttensortwo{T}
```

I think another [possible solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229543/double-tilde-symbol-under-letter) could be this, but I have some doubts about it and I have to look more carefully.

others have had experience with this?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*{\rttensor}[1]{\underline{\underline{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\rttensortwo}[1]{\bar{\bar{#1}}}

\begin{document}

$\overline{u'_{i}u'_{j}u'_{i,j}} = \rttensor{T}$
\par\bigskip
$\overline{(\rho'u'_{i})} = \rttensortwo{T}$
\end{document}
```

> I found a problem with the position of the double bar in a certain type of tensor

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{stackengine}

\newcommand*{\barbI}[1]{\stackunder[1.0pt]{$#1$}{\rule{1.0ex}{0.095ex}}} %% One bar
\newcommand*{\barbII}[1]{\barbI{\barbI{#1}}}%% double bar
\newcommand{\TRII}{\ensuremath{ \barbII{T_{R}}}} %% Tensore di Reynols 

  \begin{document}

$\TRII$ \quad\text{Tensore di Reynolds}\\

$\barbI{T}$\\

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image: pic]

-------------------**UPDATE**-----------------

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{stackengine}

\newcommand*{\barbI}[1]{\stackunder[1.0pt]{$#1$}{\rule{0.9ex}{0.095ex}}} 
\newcommand*{\barbII}[1]{\barbI{\barbI{#1}}}
\newcommand{\TRII}{\ensuremath{\barbII{\emph{T}}_{\!R}}}

  \begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
   \item $\barbII{T}_{R}$ 
    \item   $ \TRII $ < ----- Optimal Solution
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I took the liberty to add in the minimal working example (MWE). In the future please provide one when posting a question here on StackExchange.

Comment: Note that the `{\bar{\bar{#1}}}`syntax embodied in your `\rttensortwo` definition only seems to properly align the bars with Lualatex, but not with pdflatex nor xelatex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like `\barbelow` in this MWE, which can be recursively used?  Taken from my answer at [\bar below symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125412/bar-below-symbol/125415#125415)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\barbelow[1]{\stackunder[1.2pt]{$#1$}{\rule{.8ex}{.075ex}}}
\( \overline{A} \bar{A} \barbelow{A} \barbelow{\barbelow{A}} \)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes your answer is Excellent, I do not understand why in my texstudio it signals the command `\barbelow`  in red as if it were an error, but when to compile the pdf it's all ok. I would like to clarify this before closing and accepting your answer

Comment: @Antonio I don't use texstudio and so I am not quite sure.  From a LaTeX perspective, it is essential to include `stackengine` as a used package, and to define `\barbelow` (best in the preamble, though I did not do so) according to LaTeX syntax.  Perhaps this question, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299628/why-did-texstudio-suddenly-highlight-some-commands-with-red-background, would help with the red highlighting.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes yes, I read it is a problem related of the **syntax checking in TeXstudio**. it was very useful to read the post you suggested.