# Stacking thick bars below a symbol

Tags: macros, debugging, stacking-symbols, stackengine

I am using the following commands to place an arbitrary number of specialized, thick bars (`\xbar`) below a letter.

```
\documentclass[prb,preprint]{revtex4-1} 

\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\newcommand*\xbar[1]{% this command creates a specialized, thick bar
    \hbox{%
        \vbox{%
            \hrule height 0.7pt %
            \kern0.5ex%       
            \hbox{%
                \kern-0.3em%     
                \ensuremath{#1}%
                \kern-0.3em%    
            }%
        }%
    }%
}

\newcommand\xbarsbelow[2][1]{% draws n \xbar's below the given symbol
    \def\useanchorwidth{T}
    \ifnum#1>1
    \stackunder[-5pt]{\xbarsbelow[\numexpr#1-1\relax]{#2}}{\xbar{\,\,\quad}}
    \else
    \stackunder[2pt]{#2}{\xbar{\,\,\quad}}
    \fi
}

\newcommand\simplebars[2][1]{% same as \xbarsbelow, but uses the \bar symbol
    \def\useanchorwidth{T}
    \ifnum#1>1
    \stackunder[-5pt]{\simplebars[\numexpr#1-1\relax]{#2}}{\bar{}}
    \else
    \stackunder[2pt]{#2}{\bar{}}
    \fi
}

\begin{document}
$\xbarsbelow[5]{A}$, $\simplebars[5]{A}$
\end{document}
```

The commands `\xbarsbelow` and `\simplebars` are the same, except that the first uses `\xbar`, while the latter uses `\bar`.

When I use `\xbarsbelow[5]{A}`, however, it draws only 2 bars below the letter A, whereas `\simplebars[5]{A}` draws all 5.

[image: Bars]

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417310/double-bar-notation-for-second-order-tensors4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem was a very simple one.  The vertical height of `\bar` (6.77774pt) and `\xbar` (3.28333pt) are different.  Thus, when you `\stackunder` them, the gap size necessary to achieve your look needs to be different.  Thus, simply changing the `[-5pt]` gap in the `\xbarsbelow` definition to `[-1.65pt]` fixed the result.

Using `[-5pt]` as the stacking gap for `\bar` squeezed out some of the excess vertical space that comes with 6.77774pt `\bar`.  However, `\xbar` takes up a lesser vertical footprint, indeed, less than 5pt.  So using a `[-5pt]` vertical gap for successive `\xbarsbelow` eats up too much vertical space.  **In essence, you were laying each successive `\xbarbelow` atop the prior one.**

```
\documentclass[prb,preprint]{revtex4-1} 

\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\newcommand*\xbar[1]{% this command creates a specialized, thick bar
    \hbox{%
        \vbox{%
            \hrule height 0.7pt %
            \kern0.5ex%       
            \hbox{%
                \kern-0.3em%     
                \ensuremath{#1}%
                \kern-0.3em%    
            }%
        }%
    }%
}

\newcommand\xbarsbelow[2][1]{% draws n \xbar's below the given symbol
    \def\useanchorwidth{T}
    \ifnum#1>1
    \stackunder[-1.65pt]{\xbarsbelow[\numexpr#1-1\relax]{#2}}{\xbar{\,\,\quad}}
    \else
    \stackunder[2pt]{#2}{\xbar{\,\,\quad}}
    \fi
}

\newcommand\simplebars[2][1]{% same as \xbarsbelow, but uses the \bar symbol
    \def\useanchorwidth{T}
    \ifnum#1>1
    \stackunder[-5pt]{\simplebars[\numexpr#1-1\relax]{#2}}{\bar{}}
    \else
    \stackunder[2pt]{#2}{\bar{}}
    \fi
}

\begin{document}
$\xbarsbelow[5]{A}$, $\simplebars[5]{A}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

An implementation without stacks. The optional argument is for fine adjustment of the bar width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{expl3} % for \prg_replicate:nn

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xbarsbelow}[3][1]{%
  % #1 = kerning
  % #2 = repetitions
  % #3 = symbol to underbar
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th\mkern-#1mu #3\mkern-#1mu$}%
  \mkern#1mu
  \vtop{\box\z@\replicate{#2}{\kern0.7pt\hrule height 0.7pt\relax}}
  \mkern#1mu
 }
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \replicate \prg_replicate:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
A+\mathrm{A} \\
\xbarsbelow{5}{A}+\xbarsbelow[0]{3}{\mathrm{A}}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I am not entirely sure why your `\xbarsbelow` macro does not work given that it is almost exactly the same as `\simplebars`, which does work. I suspect that the problem is in the way that you are using `\numexpr` because, as I'll show below, everything is being expanded quite late.

One way to trouble shoot what is happening is to add commands like:

```
 \typeout{xbarsbelow: 1=#1, 2=#2.}
```

to your macros. In this case you will see things like

```
xbarsbelow: 1=\numexpr \numexpr \numexpr 5-1\relax -1\relax -1\relax, 2=A.
```

in your log file (or on the command line), which is probably not what you want. Using `\the\numexpr#1-1\relax` produces better results in terms of the output from  `\typeout{...}` but it does not fix the problem.

Instead, I suggest using `\stackunder` to control your recursion:

```
\newcommand\xbarsbelow[2][1]{% draws n \xbar's below the given symbol
    \def\useanchorwidth{T}% not sure what this does?
    \ifnum#1>1%
      \rlap{\stackunder[\the\dimexpr2pt*#1\relax]{\phantom{#2}}{\xbar{\,\,\quad}}}%
      \xbarsbelow[\the\numexpr#1-1\relax]{#2}
    \else%
    \stackunder[2pt]{#2}{\xbar{\,\,\quad}}%
    \fi%
}
```

This produces the desired output. The trick is to use `\rlap{...}` that, roughly speaking, prints something "without moving the cursor". In fact, if you take this approach you do not even need to use `stackengine` and can instead just use `\rule` to draw your lines:

```
\newcommand\xbarsbelow[2][1]{% draws n \xbar's below the given symbol
    \ifnum#1>0%
      \rlap{\rule[\the\dimexpr-2pt*#1\relax]{1em}{0.8pt}}%
      \xbarsbelow[\the\numexpr#1-1\relax]{#2}% recursion
    \else%
      \rlap{\hbox to 1em{\hfil$#2$\hfil}}%
      \hspace*{1em}%
    \fi%
}
```

Another option is to use `tikz`, which is what my `\newbars` macro in the code below does. This command takes a second optional argument that specifies the width of the bars. Still, the version of `\xbarsbelow` based on `\rule` is simpler and hence probably preferable -- and you could add an optional width command to it in exctly the same way.

With this is place you can produce:

[image]

using the MWE:

```
\documentclass[prb,preprint]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\newcommand*\xbar[1]{% this command creates a specialized, thick bar
    \hbox{%
        \vbox{%
            \hrule height 0.7pt %
            \kern0.5ex%
            \hbox{%
                \kern-0.3em%
                \ensuremath{#1}%
                \kern-0.3em%
            }%
        }%
    }%
}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

% usage: \newbar{A} or \newbar[3]{A} or \newbar[3](2em){A} or \newbar(2em){A}
\NewDocumentCommand\newbar{ O{1} D(){1.0em} m }{%
  \tikz[baseline=(text.base)]{\node (text) at (0,0){#3};
     \foreach \li [evaluate=\li as \y using (-0.1-0.08*\li)] in {1,...,#1}{
         \draw[thick](-#2/2,\y)--++(#2,0);
      }
   }%
}
\newcommand\xbarsbelow[2][1]{% draws n \xbar's below the given symbol
    \ifnum#1>0%
      \rlap{\rule[\the\dimexpr-2pt*#1\relax]{1em}{0.8pt}}%
      \xbarsbelow[\the\numexpr#1-1\relax]{#2}% recursion
    \else%
      \rlap{\hbox to 1em{\hfil$#2$\hfil}}%
      \hspace*{1em}%
    \fi%
}

\newcommand\simplebars[2][1]{% same as \xbarsbelow, but uses the \bar symbol
    \def\useanchorwidth{T}%
    \ifnum#1>1%
    \stackunder[-5pt]{\simplebars[\the\numexpr#1-1\relax]{#2}}{\bar{}}%
    \else%
    \stackunder[2pt]{#2}{\bar{}}%
    \fi%
}

\begin{document}
$\xbarsbelow[5]{A}$, $\simplebars[5]{A}$
$\newbar[5]{A}$

$\newbar[5](2em){A}$
\end{document}
```

Btw, I am not sure what adding `\def\useanchorwidth{T}` does inside your macros, perhaps it is some `stackengine` magic? It is also a good idea to add `%` at the end of every line of your macros as this helps to prevent unwanted space from creeping in.

In fact, rather han hard-wiring in the width of the lines it is probably better to set these automatically using the text:

```
\documentclass[prb,preprint]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{xparse}
\newlength\barlength
\newcommand\xbarsbelowrecursion[1]{%
    \ifnum#1>0%
      \rlap{\rule[\the\dimexpr-2pt*#1\relax]{\barlength}{0.7pt}}
      \xbarsbelowrecursion{\the\numexpr#1-1\relax}
    \fi%
}
\NewDocumentCommand\xbarsbelow{O{1} d() m}{% draws n \xbar's below the given symbol
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}{\settowidth\barlength{\,#3}}{\setlength\barlength{#2}}%
    \xbarsbelowrecursion{#1}%
    \rlap{\hbox to \barlength{\hfil$#3$\hfil}}%
    \hspace*{\barlength}%
}

\begin{document}
  $\xbarsbelow[5]{A}$
  $\xbarsbelow[3]{Hello}$
  $\xbarsbelow[3](4em){Hello}$
\end{document}
```

Again, there is an optional `()`-delimited argument for over-riding the length. Here's the output:

[image]